# Service Reference Update : generating redundant files

Tags: c#, wcf

When we `Add Service Reference`, Visual Studio creates xsd files as below:

1. MyService1.xsd
2. MyService2.xsd
3. MyService3.xsd

Along with wsdl and .svcmap files.

On subsequent updates, using `Update Service Refernce`, **rather than** updating above files VS 2010 keep adding more & more files appending their names..

1. MyService31.xsd
2. MyService32.xsd
3. MyService33.xsd
   **....**

This creates trouble while checking-in files & scheduled builds in continuous integration environment fails. :-( without any mistake on coding side.

How do you handle this scenario ? Can we force `Visual Studio` to force update existing files ?

Comment: It should be reusing the files be default, not sure what is causing them to create new files every time. What SVN are you using? Maybe the files are being set to readonly and prevent visual studio from being able to update the files?

Comment: i'm guessing this is TFS

Comment: @JeremyK, @Clinton We use `IBM Clearcase` for version control. However I think readonly attribute of files should not be the reason for generating new files... Since there are other readonly files in the solutions like...1. Reference.cs  2. Web.Config 3. .svcmap file.. Firing `Service Reference Update` command prompts me, to overwrite/checkout these files..

Comment: I've also had esoteric problems with Visual Studio's Add/Update Service Reference function that's why I switched to use svcutil+command files. Let me know if you want to give it a try, I can send you samples of such command files.

Comment: I think readonly is the problem... Try this yourself. Create a text file and then set it to read only. Now right a fuction that opens the file for edit, you will get an exception. If the files are read only and you are trying to update the reference, it will not be able to.

Comment: @JeremyK I did checkout the whole Service Reference folder.. Earlier I use to have files MyService1.xsd, MyService2.xsd, MyService3.xsd, On update I could see files like MyService31.xsd... MyService33.xsd

Comment: I will have to look at my solutions when I get a chance, but I have never had this happen with default settings. My only guess is that there is an option to generate a new one everytime that you selected when creating or during the update. Check the service settings.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using svcutil for both generating metadata (wsdl+xsd) and generating proxy code.

The nice thing about it that no 'behind the scenes magic' happens; you see and control every aspect.

- Create a cmd file for getting the WSDL+XSDs for the service. Run the cmd whenever your service interface changes. Add the resulting wsdl and xsd files to source control as you would do with any other external dependency (eg. 3rd party dlls). Svcutil can pull down the metadata from a url, or extract it from a .net dll if you also have the assembly implementing the service.
- Create a cmd file for (re)generating the proxy code. Run it whenever the service metadata change. Add the resulting .cs file to your project.

The cmd file would look something like this. You can define namespace mapping, serializer, collection usage, etc. Check svcutil's help.

svcutil.exe .\References\MyService\*.wsdl .\References\MyService\*.xsd
 /namespace:*,MyNamespace
 /out:.\Source\MySubfolders\MySeviceProxy.cs
 /serializer:DataContractSerializer
 /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1

Comment: Doesn't really help him with his question.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't answer the question why visual studio does this, but suggests an alternative solution for handling service metadata, which can help avoid the problem of the xsd filenames. I don't think it will happen if svcutil is used directly.

Comment: It shouldn't be happening in the first place. I use both methods and they have their tradeoffs, but I have never seen what he is experiencing and it is probably not the solution but something else getting in the way. Pushing him down a different solution as opposed to fixing the problem is a waste of time imo. If he doesn't need to make custom changes to the interface, right clicking and updating is far more convenient then having to run external tools and copy/paste every time you make an update.

Answer (score 0):

Before you attempt to update your service reference, checkout the auto generated files so VS has access to those files. I believe your files are being locked, preventing visual studio from being able to change them. This would result in what you are seeing.

Comment: I did checkedout the whole Service Reference folder.. Earlier I use to have files `MyService1.xsd, MyService2.xsd, MyService3.xsd`, On update I could see files like `MyService31.xsd... MyService33.xsd`